# Btn-group not stretching width of table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with a table header and a table row. The header is a btn-group, with 12 buttons to resemble months of a calendar, the row is of 31 columns. I want the btn-group to distribute evenly & stretch the full width of the table row. I can add **style="width:100px;"** to each button, but that's not responsive, and I don't necessarily know the width of the full table.

Can anyone see what I need to add to my code?

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="31">
        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Feb</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Apr</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">May</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jun</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jul</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Aug</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sep</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Oct</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Nov</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dec</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Here is the css tag I changed from the Bootstrap 3 defaults:

.btn-group {
    width:100%;
}

.btn-toolbar {
    width:100%;
}

[image: Btn-group not full width]

If I use btn-group-justified, it looks like this:

[image: btn-group-justified]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following class to the parent container: `.btn-group-justified`

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th colspan="31">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jan</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Feb</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Apr</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">May</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jun</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jul</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Aug</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sep</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Oct</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Nov</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dec</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </th>
</tr>
```

and for even more reference, read the following part of the documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

Comment: And wrap every <button> in `<div class="btn-group"></div>`. From the docs: _"To use justified button groups with <button> elements, you must wrap each button in a button group"_ http://jsbin.com/witij/1/edit

Comment: Thank you all. Adding the extra div class with the btn-group-justified solved the issue.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark my answer as the correct one. Thank you very much.